# Is it possible to set document.title with tampermonkey (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, document, tampermonkey, titlebar

Is it possible to set `document.title` with tampermonkey?

I am using Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit)

Here is my script (it does not work):

```
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.title = "WKRP";
})();
```

Comment: Missing `// ==UserScript==` as the first line.

Comment: I did not include it here by accident, it was in original script.
However, the problem was resolved after I updated tampermonkey by running "Check for usercript updates"